# Do all modern video cards have multi-monitor support?

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card

I am considering either the 1024MB nVidia GeForce GT220 OR the ATI Radeon HD 5670 1GB GDDR5 on a new Dell and want to be able to run dual monitors. It is difficult to get a straight answer from Dell.

Comment: @Bobby, this "Rule of thumb" is fairly inaccurate. My Radeon HD 4870 has HDMI, DisplayPort, DVI and VGA. As this card doesn't have Eyefinity support, only two ports at a time are active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the connectors are different, it is really hard to say. I've had several video cards with two different connectors and only 1 works at a time. Both the [nVidia GeForce GT220](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_gt_220_us.html)  and [ATI Radeon HD 5670](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/ati-radeon-hd-5670-overview/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-5670-specifications.aspx) say they supports multiple monitors.

According to those they both support multiple, **but to be safe, if the Dell site isn't telling you, you should [call up](http://www.dell.com/content/topics/segtopic.aspx/contact_us?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs) Dell to make sure before purchasing.** (Since these cards are produced by many manufactures who don't always follow the specifications exactly).

Comment: Thanks for this.  I did call Dell but you know that feeling you get when someone tells you something but it sounds like they are speaking without experience?  That was what it was like.   Anyway, I went with the ATI Radeon (even their site was not that clear).  Thanks ...